# Query XML stored in C# string

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have to read some values from XML,below is my sample XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ParentNode xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ChildNode>
    <GrandChild Name="title" Value="Mr" />
    <GrandChild Name="Name" Value="Test" />
    <GrandChild Name="Age" Value="25" />
    <GrandChild Name="Gender" Value="Male" />  
  </ChildNode>
</ParentNode>
```

I have to read values of Name and Age nodes, this is how I am doing

```csharp
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(myXMLstring);

var nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/ParentNode/ChildNode");
foreach (XmlNode childrenNode in nodes)
{
}
```

but this code is running for only once, I tried this inside loop,buts its not running

```
var gchild= childrenNode.SelectNodes("/GrandChild");
foreach (XmlNode namevalue in gchild)
{
}
```

How can I get the values of `Name` and `Age` node?

Comment: I don't see anything under `<ChildNode>`.

Comment: Modify `var gchild= childrenNode.SelectNodes("/GrandChild ");`  to `var gchild= childrenNode.SelectNodes("GrandChild ");` (without leading slash)

Comment: there are <GrandChild> under <ChildNode>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML contains only a single `ChildNode` so the XPATH expression `/ParentNode/ChildNode` will return only a single result. If you wanted to iterate over the grandchildren you should use `/ParentNode/ChildNode/GrandChild` or `//GrandChild`, eg:

```
var nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/ParentNode/ChildNode/GrandChild");
```

The result will be the same.

A single slash at the start of an XPath expression means that the path starts from the root, so `/GrandChild` returns nothing because there is no `GrandChild` note at the root level. A double slash `//` means wherever in the hierarchy, so `//GrandChild` will return all `GrandChild` nodes in the file

Answer (score 1):

`SelectNodes` uses XPath expressions. In XPath, if the expression stars with `/` it'll start selecting relative to root.

Just use a relative xpath expression. In your case:

```
var gchild = childrenNode.SelectNodes("./GrandChild");
```

Or the equivalent:

```
var gchild = childrenNode.SelectNodes("GrandChild");
```

Or, if you **only** aim to iterate over those `GrandChild` elements, there's no reason to select the `ChildNode` first, you could iterate directly:

```
var nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/ParentNode/ChildNode/GrandChild");
```